# JIRA - Show story dependencies on Greenhopper cards

Tags: jira, greenhopper

We have some 250 stories for an upcoming project, entered into Jira/Greenhopper.

Some "Business stories" depend on certain "Tech stories" being completed before they can be started.

The dependencies have been created using the conventional Jira linking function.

On the cards displayed in Greenhopper I would like to display a list of dependencies, so that we can move such dependencies into releases during our release planning.

Does anyone have any ideas how this might be done?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible (yet). There are some issues on the Atlassian site that you can vote on though to show your interest in this.